# How to 'quickly' add row data values in pandas with respect to a certain column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Please see the attached image below.
I have a data set which record value for each time instance (Time Stamp) in the data set. 
Now, I want a single data record (for each column) for any given time. For example, the red box (for 'Time Stamp' 23054350) that I have made should sum up to be a single 'SMS in', 'SMS out', 'Call in' etc.
Similar example can be seen for other 'Time Stamp'. Note that all the instances of time should be summed together.

I know I can run a loop to solve this problem. But my data is very huge and I have multiple files (of huge data per file) and running a loop is very inefficient. Can I do it in a quicker way, sort of using vectorized implementation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
df.groupby(['Grid ID', 'Time Stamp'], as_index = False).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.groupby('Time Stamp').sum()
```